# Conditional redirect in laravel after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to redirect after login with condition in laravel 5.4,
As Like:

```
   if (Auth::user()->id==1) {
       return redirect('admin');
   }
   else { 
       return redirect('/');
   }
```

How to implement the condition.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as provided.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add following code in **LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Login Controller
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
  | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
  | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
  |
  */

  use AuthenticatesUsers;

   /**
    * Where to redirect users after login.
    *
    * @var string
    */
   //protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

   /**
    * Create a new controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {// do your magic here
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: if you make a login attempt twice it redirects to the admin dash board ..

Answer (score 1):

@Al-Amin to redirect after login successfully based on role id you can override authenticated(Request $request, $user) function in your Auth Controller or Login Controller if you have in below manner :

```
/**
     * [authenticated is used to redirect user after login based on role]
     * @param  Request $request [request object]
     * @param  [type]  $user    [user object to check user role]
     * @return [type]           [return type]
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if($user->role->id == 1) {
            return redirect()->intended('/admin'); // it will be according to your routes.

        } else {
            return redirect()->intended('/'); // it also be according to your need and routes
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work,
but if use for redirect 

            redirect('/admin');


then works

Answer (score 0):

This is the method which you should change in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard'); // Change this line 
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```